# MSVC compiled code hits debug assert when using _Atomic float

Tags: c, visual-c++, c11, stdatomic, compiler-bug

I have the following code:

```c
static _Atomic float testf;
void func() {
   testf=1.0f;
   float f=testf;
   printf("%f\n", f);
}
```

Running it causes the program to hit a Debug Assert, Invalid memory order, at vcruntime_c11_atomic_support.h:417. (MSVC version 19.37.32822.0).

I'm not that familiar with x64 calling conventions, but it looks like the generated assembly isn't calling either one of _Atomic_store32 or _Atomic_load32 correctly:

```c
inline void _Atomic_store32(volatile int* _Ptr, int _Desired, int _Order);
inline int _Atomic_load32(const volatile int* _Ptr, int _Order);
```

```asm
; 41   :     testf=1.0f;

    mov r8d, 5    ; !!This seems to be _Order, corresponding to _Atomic_memory_order_seq_cst
    movss   xmm1, DWORD PTR __real@3f800000
    lea rcx, OFFSET FLAT:testf
    call    _Atomic_store32   ; !!Where is EDX? That should contain _Desired.

; 42   :     float f=testf;

    movss   xmm1, DWORD PTR __real@40a00000
    lea rcx, OFFSET FLAT:testf
    call    _Atomic_load32    ; !!EDX should have _Order.
    movss   DWORD PTR f$[rsp], xmm0
```

Is MSVC atomic support bugged, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like a compiler bug from that asm output.

It's like the compiler wants to call `_Atomic_store32(void*, float)` since it's passing the second arg in XMM1.  But that's the same function it uses for integers, I assume, so yeah the actual arg needs to be in EDX.  Treating it like a variadic function would work for the Win x64 calling convention, since those functions need XMM args to be copied to the corresponding integer reg.

For the load, `movss   xmm1, DWORD PTR __real@40a00000` is loading a float constant with bit-pattern `0x40a00000` into the second arg-passing register (for FP args).  That bit-pattern represents `5.0f`, so MSVC has got itself very confused about something, doing `_Atomic_load32(&testf, (float)memory_order_seq_cst)` with those arg types.

Emitting code like that is definitely a sign of a compiler bug.  (And nice job constructing a minimal test-case and showing the relevant asm.  You could submit this exact example to MS's compiler team and they'd very quickly see the symptoms of something being wrong.)